# Call git pull from emacs hang emacs

Tags: git, shell, emacs, ssh, git-pull

Evaluate `(shell-command-to-string "git pull -q")` in emacs *scratch* buffer hangs emacs.

From `htop` in bash,I noticed that after the `git pull` process which is forked from emacs ended,there always leave a ssh process **ssh: git@myrepo.org:22** whose parameter is my remote git repository URL.
And once there is the *ssh* process,`(shell-command-to-string "git pull -q")` normally exit.

Besides `git pull -q` works normally under bash.

Additional system info `uname -a`:
Linux Edge 3.8.0-31-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 11 17:49:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Any guy has any idea?

Comment: Are you using an SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this on my box but could not. The buffer evaluates fine.

On a tangent, if you want to interact with Git repositories from Emacs, you will be better off using the `magit` [package](https://github.com/magit/magit).

Comment: I have been using `magit`,and `(magit-git-exit-code "git pull -q")` produces same result.

Comment: I may be missing the specifics of what you are trying to do. If I had to do this, I will do `(magit-pull)`. Is there any reason you can't use that?

Comment: I want a batched `git pull` & `git push` to auto synchronize stuff,only cares the exit status.